# How to prevent UITextField to add phrase end point?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

When you type "aa" space space UITextField auto correct the text as "aa. ".
I don't want the end point and cannot find how to prevent this behaviour.
I tried UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo with no success.

Anybody have a solution ?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code where you instantiate `UITextField` and its settings.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to change this behavior by code.

The user must go in Settings, General, Keyboard and disable the "." Shortcut.

Good luck!